# Matching two patterns in one python regex, capturing only non-empty values

Tags: python, regex

After a lot of searching and reading, I am not really sure what I am trying to do is possible in one step. I want it to either match this:

```
(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})

2011/12/13
```

or this

```
(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,2})

12/2011/13
```

or this

```
(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,2})

12/13/2011
```

in one regex and capture the values in the parentheses.

---

So what I did was wrap those three is non-capturing `or` statements:

```
^(?:(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2}))|(?:(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,4})/(\d{1,2}))|(?:(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,4}))$
```

The only problem is if use it on this

```
2011/12/13
```

what I get is this:

```
2100
10
10
Empty
Empty
Empty
Empty
Empty
Empty
```

I do not really like the empty captures. Can I set them so only non-mpty strings are returned?!

I can think of a lot of workarounds to still make this work, starting from first matching the correct pattern and then matching the correct captures, to checking the captured values for having more than an empty string, but it seems to me this should be possible in the regex itself.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?:(?=\d{1,4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})|(?=\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,2})|(?=\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}))(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$
```

The 3 look ahead make sure you have a date in any of the 3 formats, then capture the 3 elements of the date.

**explanation:**

```
^                              : begining of the string
(?:                            : begin non capture group
  (?=\d{1,4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})  : assume the format is yyyy/mm/dd
  |                            : or
  (?=\d{1,2}/\d{1,4}/\d{1,2})  : format dd/yyyy/mm
  |                            : or
  (?=\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,4})  : format dd/mm/yyyy
)                              : end of non capture group
(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)              : capture the 3 elements
$                              : end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my stab (short and sweet):

```
(\d{2,4})(?=/)/(\d{2,4})(?=/)/(\d{2,4})$
```

Comment: Much more shorter than mine, but it matches `123/1234/789`

Comment: You are correct sir! I'll leave it here in case it's useful (i.e. data may be guaranteed to be in one of the three stated formats), but if that's not the case, use M42's answer.